# convert two input files into certain string rules by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, python-re, readlines

Let's say there are two input files as below:
`input1.txt` (only composed of `hstep3_*`)

```
hstep3_num00 = a5;
hstep3_num01 = 3b;
hstep3_num02 = 4f;
hstep3_num03 = 27;
```

`input2.txt` ( the letters inside brackets are some random characters split by `,`)

```
some random strings that are not 'hstep' form
... 
match hstep1_num00 = {eau,t,nb,v,d}; // MATCH
match hstep1_num01 = {c,bul,kv,e}; // MATCH
... 
match hstep3_num00 = {u_ku,b,ntv,q}; // MATCH
match hstep3_num01 = {qq,rask,cb_p}; // MATCH
match hstep3_num02 = {c,a,ha,w,ykl}; // MATCH
match hstep3_num03 = {p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d}; // MATCH
...
some random strings that are not 'hstep' form
```

and What I want to do is to sort out all the left hand side of equation from `input1.txt`, and match the corresponding bracket and value from `input2.txt`.

So, the final output.txt looks as follows:
`output.txt`

```
{u_ku,b,ntv,q}     = a5;
{qq,rask,cb_p}     = 3b;
{c,a,ha,w,ykl}     = 4f;
{p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d} = 27;
```

In order to do so by python, I've thought about `readlines.split()`.
Also, since the number of Characters inside bracket are not always same by lines, I thought I have to use regular expressions to limit the range inside `{}`
but It doesn't work as I expected...
Anybody give me any solutions or guidelines for this?

Any help would be much appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. What are the criteria for a MATCH to happen? Do you have an explanation as to why {u_ku,b,ntv,q} got matched with a5?

Comment: @MuhammadShamshadAslam The criteria itself and the value of 'a5' itself are meaningless in here!!.. I just wanted to match the all the right hand side of input2.txt to its value written in input1.txt

Comment: Use regular expressions and dictionaries. Show the code you have written and the error message or incorrect output you are getting.

Comment: It’s not really clear to me what exactly you are asking. Are you asking about  reading the `match …` lines from the file, discarding the noise? Are you asking about matching the lines with same `hstep…` key? Are you asking about your failed attempt using regex? Something else? Please consider to [edit] your question to *focus* on one specific issue.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am asking about matching just hstep3_num00~03 and then take the value from input1.txt . not the string 'match' and 'MATCH'.. these 'match' words can be changed anyhow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is not optimized, but it's so OP understands the processes involved a bit better

```py
# read input1 and turn into dict
input1 = {}
with open("input1.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        key, value = line.split(" = ")
        input1[key] = value

# read input 2 and store the maxlen value
input2 = []
maxlen = 0
with open("input2.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        # only process lines that start with "match hstep3"
        if line.startswith("match hstep3"):
            key = line.split(" ")[1]
            value = line.split("= ")[1].split(";")[0]
            input2.append([key, value])
            # get the maxlength and store it for future use
            maxlen = max(maxlen, len(value))

# finally, produce the required output and write to file
with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in input2:
        key, value = line
        # use an f-string to produce the required output
        newline = f"{value:<{maxlen}} = {input1[key]}"
        outfile.write(newline)
```

`output.txt` file contents:

```
{u_ku,b,ntv,q}     = a5;
{qq,rask,cb_p}     = 3b;
{c,a,ha,w,ykl}     = 4f;
{p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d} = 27;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two loops with a regex. A first one with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to read the lines from `input2.txt` and build a dictionary if matches, and a second loop on `input1.txt` to perform the substitutions with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
with open('input2.txt') as f2:
    dic = dict(re.findall(fr'match ([^\s=]+) = ([^;]+); // MATCH', f2.read()))
# {'hstep1_num00': '{eau,t,nb,v,d}', 'hstep1_num01': '{c,bul,kv,e}',
#  'hstep3_num00': '{u_ku,b,ntv,q}', 'hstep3_num01': '{qq,rask,cb_p}',
#  'hstep3_num02': '{c,a,ha,w,ykl}', 'hstep3_num03': '{p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d}'}

with open('input1.txt') as f1, open('output1.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f1:
        f_out.write(re.sub(r'^\S+', lambda m: dic.get(m.group(), ''), line))
```

Output file:

```
{u_ku,b,ntv,q} = a5;
{qq,rask,cb_p} = 3b;
{c,a,ha,w,ykl} = 4f;
{p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d} = 27;
```

[regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/yhbu1P/1), [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PKgppV/1)

##### alignment

If alignment of the strings is needed, then you can modify the above approach.

fixed width (or based on the maximum possible width):

```
import re

# same as previously
with open('input2.txt') as f2:
    dic = dict(re.findall(fr'match ([^\s=]+) = ([^;]+); // MATCH', f2.read()))

WIDTH = max([len(v) for k,v in dic.items() if k.startswith('hstep3_')])

with open('input1.txt') as f1, open('output1.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f1:
        f_out.write(re.sub(r'^\S+', lambda m: dic.get(m.group(), '').ljust(WIDTH), line))
```

Dynamic width, based on the longest string:

```
import re

# same as previously
with open('input2.txt') as f2:
    dic = dict(re.findall(fr'match ([^\s=]+) = ([^;]+); // MATCH', f2.read()))

with open('input1.txt') as f1:
    WIDTH = max(len(dic.get(line.split(maxsplit=1)[0], '')) for line in f1)

with open('input1.txt') as f1, open('output1.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f1:
        f_out.write(re.sub(r'^\S+', lambda m: dic.get(m.group(), '').ljust(WIDTH), line))
```

Output:

```
{u_ku,b,ntv,q}     = a5;
{qq,rask,cb_p}     = 3b;
{c,a,ha,w,ykl}     = 4f;
{p,gu,enb_q_b,z,d} = 27;
```

Comment: @DarkKnight what did I miss?

Comment: Variable spacing so that everything's right aligned

Comment: @DarkKnight is this a requirement? Not explicitly mentioned, then what are the rules? longer string? Fixed maximum?

Comment: Anyway, quite easy to handle, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the format as you mentioned OR close to it then this should work.

```
result_2_dict = {}
result_1_dict = {}
file_2_list= []
file_1_list = []

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.split('=')
        file_2_list.append(parts)

for item in file_2_list:
    if "h" in item[0]:
        result_2_dict[item[0].strip("match").strip() ] = item[1].strip().split(" ")[0].strip(";")


with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.split('=')
        file_1_list.append(parts)

for item in file_1_list:
    if "h" in item[0]:
        result_1_dict[item[0].strip()] = item[1].strip().strip(";")


matches_values = {}

for key, value in result_2_dict.items():
    if key in result_1_dict:
        matches_values[value] = result_1_dict[key]


    
for key, value in matches_values.items():
    print(f"{key} = {value}")
```